# Activate script after scrolling down

Tags: jquery, scroll, locking, scrolltop

I'm using this code to lock my site. I'm new to jQuery.

I want it to lock my site after scrolling 1500px;

I guess I have to use .scrollTop, but I've tried it but it isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {

        $.scrollLock(['#lock']);

    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

This is the script: https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/6550066

Bonus question:
Is it possible for the page to unlock on a submit button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb6HF/

JavaScript

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 500) { 
        $.scrollLock();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is working, but when it locks my site it jumps back to the beginning. I want the site to lock on the position it is (like 500 in your example). Try scrolling on my site and see what happens: http://stilld.nl/brrreuk/

Comment: I updated my fiddle, but can't confirm this? http://jsfiddle.net/Xb6HF/1/ Just use "$.scrollLock();" not "$.scrollLock('#lock')"; This is the ID of your body and I think that is the problem.

Comment: Then it has something to do with your paralax scripts. Maybe one of these is listening to the scrolling of the document and when you disable the scrolling it 'thinks' that you have scrolled to top. You should maybe read the manual of your paralax script and the if there is a solution for you.

Comment: Mhh, that could be the problem. I have no idea where to look, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe ask on the github site. You could create an issue and describe your problem. If you are lucky, they will add a feature like that in a future release. In the meantime you could check out http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/. It is really powerful!